# matrix subseting by column's name using `subset` function

Tags: r, debugging, matrix, dataframe, subset

Consider the following simulation snippet:

```
k <- 1:5
x <- seq(0,10,length.out =  100)
dsts <- lapply(1:length(k), function(i) cbind(x=x, distri=dchisq(x,k[i]),i) )
dsts <- do.call(rbind,dsts)
```

why does this code throws an error (dsts is matrix):

```
subset(dsts,i==1)
#Error in subset.matrix(dsts, i == 1) : object 'i' not found
```

Even this one:

```
colnames(dsts)[3] <- 'iii'
subset(dsts,iii==1)
```

But not this one (matrix coerced as dataframe):

```
subset(as.data.frame(dsts),i==1)
```

This one works either where `x` is already defined:

```
subset(dsts,x> 500)
```

The error occurs in `subset.matrix()` on this line:

```
else if (!is.logical(subset))
```

Is this a bug that should be reported to R Core?

Comment: Column name evaluation only works for data.frames, not matrices. That's just how subset is designed to work. It's described in the documentation. This is not a bug.

Comment: You will be pleased to hear that this function is not recommended for non-interactive use: `This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I had read the doc already. What does `interactively` mean here?

Comment: Anything which is run through Rscript is non-interactive.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik so I am testing the function interactively here. No Rscript!

Comment: @aichao it's not clear how your example should work. OP already has a column with defined variable which should be used for subsetting.

Comment: When they say that it's for interactive use, they really are talking about the non-standard evaluation (which oddly has become more standard now). People often get confused when using `subset()` to loop over different columns programmatically, or like when they try to pass filters as parameters to functions. It's a safe function, you just need to carefully understand how it works before you do "advanced" things with it.

Comment: @MrFlick I would be interested in reading about column evaluation and how this works out the fact that `subset(dsts, i > 1)` doesn't work and `subset(dsts, x > 9)` does.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik `x` exists outside the matrix in this example. And it happens to be in the same order as it is in the matrix. The second example is using `x` form the global environment. Basically data.frames are lists so they can act like environments where variables can be looked up. Matrices are basically just dimensioned vectors and do not behave the same way.

Comment: The take away lesson here is that unless you have a need for matrix arithmetic, you're probably better off storing your data in a data.frame. That's the R-way. You can use `cbind.data.frame` to be more explicit.

Comment: @MrFlick This is a very bad inconsistency and I think it can be fixed in subset.matrix function. It has already taken 2 hours of my time (think about other people running into the issue).

Comment: @MrFlick I think you should articulate your comments into a full blown answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is by design and is documented on the `?subset` help page.

From the help page:

> For data frames, the subset argument works on the rows. Note that subset will be evaluated in the data frame, so columns can be referred to (by name) as variables in the expression (see the examples).

In R, data.frames and matrices are very different types of objects. If this is causing a problem, you are probably using the wrong data structure for your data. Matrices are really only necessary if you meed matrix arithmetic. If you are thinking of your columns as different attributes for a row observations, then you should be storing your data in a data.frame in the first place. You could store all your values in a simple vector where every three values represent one observation, but that would also be a poor choice of data structure for your data. I'm not sure if you were trying to be more efficient by choosing a matrix but it seems like just the wrong choice.

A data.frame is stored as a named list while a matrix is stored as a dimensioned vector. A list can be used as an environment which makes it easy to evaluate variable names in that context. The biggest difference between the two is that data.frames can hold columns of different classes (numerics, characters, dates) while matrices can only hold values of exactly one data.type. You cannot always easily convert between the two without a loss of information.

Thinks like `$` only work with data.frames as well.

```
dd <- data.frame(x=1:10)
dd$x
mm <- matrix(1:10, ncol=1, dimnames=list(NULL, "x"))    
mm$x # Error
```

If you want to subset a matrix, you are better off using standard `[` subsetting rather than the sub setting function.

```
dsts[ dsts[,"i"]==1, ]
```

This behavior has been a part of R for a very long time. Any changes to this behavior is likely to introduce breaking changes to existing code that relies on variables being evaluated in a certain context. I think the problem lies with whomever told you to use a matrix in the first place. Rather than `cbind()`, you should have used `data.frame()`